# Git not working for angularjs.org tutorial

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, npm

I'm trying to follow the angularjs.org tutorial (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial).  It requires you to install and set up git and I'm having some trouble getting everything to work.  The directions on the tutorial are pretty straight forward so not sure where I could have gone wrong.  All default options were selected during install.

The problems start after installing node.js and TRYING to install all required tools for the project.  I tried this both in the git command line and git bash (not sure what the difference is).  After installing node.js the tutorial says to put the command `npm install` for the other tools and in git bash you get this

```
> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat
> bower install

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.7
```

Now I tried this in Git CMD first and I got something like this `npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.`  I just tried again in Git CMD and I now get what looks like the same thing that happened in bash. I have node version 5.6.0.

Anybody know where I should go from here?

### UPDATE

Okay so I ended up doing the fix posted by @Oliver Queen, except I did `npm install` from GIT Bash instead of SDK 7.1 (sdk couldn't find the directory I saved the project in, I think because I remember during the git install an option about only being able to use Git Bash and not windows cmd?).  Seems to have worked, this is what I got

```
$ npm install

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\bufferuti                                                                                                    l
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config                                                                                                    _node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\.                                                                                                    .\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,                                                                                                     please add the "/m" switch.
  bufferutil.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.c
     Creating library C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\bufferutil\bui                                                                                                    ld\Release\bufferutil.lib and object C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules                                                                                                    \bufferutil\build\Release\bufferutil.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  bufferutil.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\bufferutil\b                                                                                                    uild\Release\\bufferutil.node

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\utf-8                                                                                                    -validate
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_co                                                                                                    nfig_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\                                                                                                    ..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,                                                                                                     please add the "/m" switch.
  validation.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.c
     Creating library C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\utf-8-validate                                                                                                    \build\Release\validation.lib and object C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_mod                                                                                                    ules\utf-8-validate\build\Release\validation.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  validation.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat\node_modules\utf-8-valida                                                                                                    te\build\Release\\validation.node

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat
> bower install

angular-phonecat@0.0.0 C:\Users\Ivan\angular-phonecat
`-- protractor@2.5.1
  `-- selenium-webdriver@2.47.0
    `-- ws@0.8.1
      +-- bufferutil@1.2.1
      | +-- bindings@1.2.1
      | `-- nan@2.2.0
      `-- utf-8-validate@1.2.1
        `-- nan@2.2.0

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.7
```

As you can see at the bottom I still get

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.7
```

Do I have to worry about this?

Comment: You need to install the dependencies of [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp), e.g. Python and a version of Visual Studio.

Comment: This is a huge problem with windows. https://www.robertkehoe.com/2015/03/fix-node-gyp-rebuild-error-on-windows/ see if this works

Comment: @Oliver Queen trying it out right now, visual studio is taking forever to install.  By the way, I just remembered that one of the times I tried this I got a message saying something about javascript or node or something was unsafe on public networks (I'm on a wifi hotspot).  I believe it was a windows prompt and it suggested I should exit the program or command line or whatever.  Is this something I need to worry about?

Comment: Are you building locally?

Comment: @Oliver Queen On my computer? yes

Comment: You should be fine. When I dev node, I just pick a random port and change it every so often

Comment: @Oliver Queen got it, thanks

Comment: @Oliver Queen, still waiting for visual studio, this wifi is unbearably slow haha.  I'll post an update once I get there

Comment: @Oliver Queen hey oliver, I think the fix worked but I still get 2 npm warn messages.  I posted it in an update in the post, would you mind taking a peek and seeing if it's something I gotta worry about?